# Cannot return from function that uses zmq in python 3 django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, zeromq

I use python 3.6.6 anaconda 64 bit windows, zmq 4.2.5
I have very strange behavior: function can't return.

Server:

```
import zmq
import json

def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    #socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 1000)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, 1000)
    socket.bind(my_address)

    def send_response(**kwargs):
        try:
            #... Some kwargs standard preprocessing
            socket.send_string(json.dumps(kwargs))
        except zmq.ZMQBaseError:
            return False
        return True

    while True:
        try:
            msg = socket.recv().decode("utf-8")
        except zmq.ZMQBaseError:
            continue
        #... Processing
        if not send_response(error='Everything is wrong'):
            continue
        #... Processing
```

Client:

```
import zmq
import json

def do_request(**kwargs):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 5000)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDTIMEO, 1000)
    socket.connect(my_address)

    #... kwargs pre-rocessing
    try:
        socket.send_string(json.dumps(kwargs))
        response = json.loads(socket.recv().decode("utf-8"))
        #... Processing
        return response
    except zmq.ZMQBaseError as e:
        print(e)
        print("PING1!!!")
        return dict(error='Service temporarily unavailable', r_status=503)

def called_from_view():
    response = do_request(command='ping')
    print("PING2!!!")
```

It was working. I don't know what has changed. But now it is broken.
When server is shut down, client's `do_request` doesn't return the `Service temporarily unavailable`. The `response = json.loads(socket.recv().decode("utf-8"))` throws an exception. In `except` section python prints the `PING1`, but it doesn't print `PING2` in `called_from_view` after that. Even with the empty return. I can't figure out why.

I create new socket in `do_request` because the client's `called_from_view` is called from django's view. I had other problems before with the global socket.

Comment: Have you tried printing out your response before json loading it to see what's coming in? In your code samples, `called_from_view()` is never called, so it makes sense why `PING2!!!` is never printed. I can't look at why "Service temporarily unavailable" isn't returning because I don't see the part where "do_request" is being called from.

Comment: @jarcobi I call the `called_from_view`. The `do_request` is called from the `called_from_view`. There is an exception because the server is shut down.  The `PING1` is printed. The `do_request` never returns. I had placed prints after every lines there and printed every variable to track what it is. I've spent all day trying to understand why `do_request` doesn't return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option after creating your socket in the client (you can keep your other options too):

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, True) # or False, my testing says it works both ways.
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582128/7586861) for reference. Basically, the garbage collector is trying to pick up the pieces when returning from `do_request` and the zmq socket is stopping it from finishing and it hangs indefinitely.